# Calling method of class one to another class in android java?

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

Heys devs I have a quick question I have a method which is present in my MainActivity now I want to call that method in my LoginActivity. I have done this thing through getInstance but it give me an error which I share in below:

My method of calling :
In my MainActivity I use :

```js
private static MainActivity instance;
  instance = this;
 public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
```

In login activity I use:

```js
  MainActivity.getInstance().checktag(cnic);
```

Logcat:

```js
2020-12-02 16:22:03.897 12153-12153/info.androidhive.loginandregistration E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: info.androidhive.loginandregistration, PID: 12153
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@c69530c is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
        at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.MainActivity.showDialog(MainActivity.java:532)
        at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.MainActivity.checkmtag(MainActivity.java:308)
        at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.LoginActivity$2.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:163)
        at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.LoginActivity$2.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:134)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Any fix of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare that function as public and static and you can call them anywhere from the application. example

MainActivity.java

```
public static void some(){
   //TODO something
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
MainActivity.some();
```

Comment: No its not true

Comment: This is a basic concept of how to access the method of different class without creating instance or objects. On your case you are violating the basic life-cycle of android. You need to pass Context or Activity reference to that method for showing. e.g. public static void some(Context mContext){//TODO some code}.

Answer (score 0):

From the error logs it looks like you are trying to show a Dialog in MainActivity.checktag() function when LoginActivity is on the top. This is not allowed. The Dialog needs to be managed by the Activity which is on the top.

Updated:
To clarify, the error is not due to calling the method of MainActivity from LoginActivity. The issue here is that your code is creating a Dialog with the MainActivity context when it is not the current active activity.
If your intention is to reuse some code to show Dialog between MainActivity and LoginActivity, you could move the function to a new Utility class and then pass the current Activity instance to the function. The same could be done while keeping the code in MainActivity itself, but the former method looks cleaner in my opinion.